# How to make circled image in gimp?

Tags: gimp, design

I want to get a circular image from a rectangle image. You can see the image below, please.
[image]

Comment: use the circle select tool. then  invert selection. finally cut the back out.

Comment: ... as explained in this tutorial [Making a circle-shaped image](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/CircleImage/)

Comment: Guys, you could make your comment elaborate and instead post an answer too.

Answer (score 5):

First things first, there is actually nothing as a circular image. Images that appear circular are due to the fact that the corners are made transparent and shaped such that a circle is portrayed.

With that clarification, I believe you have a clue about what you will do.

So you can go about it as follows:

First, make sure that your layer has an “alpha channel”.

`Layer → Transparency → Add alpha channel`

If it’s greyed out it means you already have one

[image]

- Create a circular selection with the “Ellipse select tool” (the 2nd one in the toolbox).

[image]

Use the “Tool options” dialog

`Windows → Dockable dialogs → Tool options`

[image]

a) If you want a true circle, use the Fixed option: select Aspect ratio and enter 1:1.

b) Depending on what kind of marks you have, you can use:

i) The diagonal framing (default): click on one corner, drag across a full diagonal and release at the opposite corner.

ii) The radial framing (check Expand from center in the Tool options): click on the center, drag across a half diagonal release on a corner.

- If the selection isn’t perfect on the first try, you can move it (click around the middle) or extend it (click inside, near a border or a corner).
- Once you have the required selection, invert the selection (Select → Invert, or Ctrl-I) so that everything is selected, except your circle.
- Erase the selection (Edit → Clear or [Delete] key). You should have your central circle left, surrounded by a checkerboard pattern. (this checkerboard is not part of the image, it just indicates the transparent parts of the image).
- You can reduce the checkerboard to the minimum by auto-cropping the image (Image → Autocrop image)
- Last, save the image in a format that supports transparency, like PNG (JPEG doesn’t support transparent images…)
- If you are going to work further on the picture, save it as XCF (Gimp native format).

You may equally visit this link for more clarification: https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/CircleImage/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @YufenyuyVeyehDider  It is better to give solution without providing solution's link.

Comment: @alhelal did this actually work for you? Did it help?